# Extract data from specific row and column of a text file

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[image: This]

This is how my text file looks like. I want to extract data from the 'v[km/h]' column but only those specific data whose 'Vehicle Type' is 700. Extracted data can be saved in a new text file. Please help me with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over your `df` and only append the speed information to a `list` if `vehicle type == 700`

```
speed = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['Vehicle type'].loc[i] == 700:
        speed.append(df['v[km/h]'].loc[i])
```

Comment: ah apologies, its caps sensitive so 'Vehicle type'.

Comment: Showing a KeyError: 'Vehicle type'

Comment: corrected, missed a .loc[i]. The df['Vehicle type'] specifies the column and .loc[i] specifies the index of that column so we're now specifying a single cell, which we test to see if it equals 700.

Comment: import pandas as pd. df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Documents\VISSIM\Final\Final Run & Check\new_output.txt")
speed = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['Vehicle type'].loc[i] == 700:
        speed.append(df['v[km/h]'].loc[i]). Still the same error

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would continue to produce that error message is if your index has been shuffled at some point. Try running df.reset_index(drop=True) before the for loop.

Comment: Tried... Nothing's working... Thanks for the try though....

Comment: Hey the code worked. I delimited the columns and then it worked. Previously all the data were stacked in the same column. Thanks for the help